# How to render series data to a title in sencha charts

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a chart retrieving data from my store, the four bits of information are the following

Model Code

```
Ext.define('QvidiApp.model.ClipsViews', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'meta_id'
        },
        {
            name: 'title'
        },
        {
            name: 'viewed'
        },
        {
            name: 'glances'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Now I have the viewed field and  the glances field as the numeric fields in the chart, and the title field as the category title in the chart.

I want to render the title name of the field when I hover over it, reason id this. The titles are too long to fit in the x-axis of the chart so in place of the titles I am putting 'meta_id'. So when I hover over the x-axis meta_id field I want the title name to be shown

so for example

meta_id 100 will equal title value ###

Here's is my chart code so far

```
{
                            xtype: 'chart',
                            centered: true,
                            height: '150%',
                            colors: [
                                '#24ad9a',
                                '#7c7474',
                                '#a66111'
                            ],
                            store: 'ClipsViewed',
                            axes: [
                                {
                                    type: 'category',
                                    fields: [
                                        'meta_id'
                                    ],
                                    grid: true,
                                    label: {
                                        rotate: {
                                            degrees: 0
                                        },
                                        font: '7px'
                                    },
                                    title: 'Clips'
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'numeric',
                                    fields: [
                                        'viewed'
                                    ],
                                    grid: true,
                                    position: 'left',
                                    title: 'Amount'
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index) {

                                    },
                                    style: {
                                        minGapWidth: 1,
                                        minBarWidth: 60,
                                        maxBarWidth: 70,
                                        opacity: 0.80
                                    },
                                    xField: 'meta_id',
                                    yField: [
                                        'viewed',
                                        'glances'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            interactions: [
                                {
                                    type: 'panzoom'
                                }
                            ],
                            legend: {
                                xtype: 'legend'
                            }
                        }
```

As you can see in the above code I have a render function but I dont know what to put into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tips for series

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'bar',

        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 74,
            height: 38,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('meta_id') + '<br />' + storeItem.get('title'));
            }
        },
        style: {
            minGapWidth: 1,
            minBarWidth: 60,
            maxBarWidth: 70,
            opacity: 0.80
        },
        xField: 'meta_id',
        yField: [
            'viewed',
            'glances'
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi again, I see what you mean but One Question, I am using Sencha Architect, and I cant find the config option for tips inside Architect

Comment: I am using sencha Touch

Comment: I read somewhere that you can use Item info interactions instead for mobile devices, do you know how I can do the exact same thing as above with that

Comment: sorry didn't noticed you were coding in sencha touch. my solution i for extjs, I do not know how to solve your problem for touch. in sencha architect you can add custom properties, try adding `tips`, maybe that will work.

Comment: I added tips in my sencha architect and that worked so thanks for that, I will just have to work through sencha touch and try to get that item info interaction working, thanks.

Comment: Your answer helped although I would rate it up if I could

Comment: Glad to hear that. 
P.S you can mark as best answer

Comment: Just add this so that future people know that bit of code you suggested no longer works in ext 6/Sencha Version 3.5, seems like, I dont know how they could just remove it without any warning, but i replaced that code with something like this

{
trackMouse: true,
height: 30,
renderer: function(tip, item) {
    tip.update(item.get('types') + ': ' + item.get('counter'));
}
}